# Intent Based Android Security Vulnerabilities, Violating the Device and Network Abuse policy

Tags: android, google-play, android-security, startactivityforresult, android-securityexception

We have got this mail from google says,

During review, we found that your app violates the Device and Network Abuse policy:

We don’t allow code that introduces or exploits security vulnerabilities. Check out the App Security Improvement Program to find out about the most recent security issues flagged to developers.
You can read through the Device and Network Abuse policy page for more details and examples of common violations.

For example, your app contains an **Intent Redirection** issue which can allow malicious apps to access private app components or files.

**androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult**

...................................................

We replaced *ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult* with *registerForActivityResult*
Am I missing anything else.

Google is not specific about the source of the cause

What could be the source of the cause, how to overcome it?

Comment: Google have [an FAQ](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en) for this specific vulnerability.

Comment: Followed that, but no luck Michael